# kelp on Arduino/raspberry pi

Tags: kelp

Has anyone done this before? I got a couple of boards collecting dust, was wondering if I could run kelp Kelp on it. Or if someone already tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to easily run Kelp on a Raspberry Pi (don't know about Arduino). Kelp uses very little CPU and has very little memory requirements -- both these requirements are dependent on the trading strategy used.

I have been including [arm-based binary releases](https://github.com/stellar/kelp/releases) since the very first release ([v1.0.0-rc1](https://github.com/stellar/kelp/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc1)) of Kelp with the express purpose of supporting Kelp on the Raspberry Pi. I have not tried it myself, but that sounds like a fun project!

If you attempt to run Kelp on a Raspberry Pi and choose to write a blog post on what the experience is like, then I will include it in the SDF newsletter for promotion.

Nikhil

Developer of Kelp (on behalf of SDF)